# Xampp filter page access on ip level

Tags: xampp, httpd.conf, lan

I have a local network website which works on lan mainly works user registration and approval and i need to make user registartion page only for specific ips for other users i need to show them full webpage incluing login and approvals.

> 192.168.0.1/regis.php

Someusers withsome specific ip only they can access this page.not approval
And some users with another specific ip can access all including regis.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict access to resources using Require.

From Apache documentation:

> The authorization providers implemented by mod_authz_host are
> registered using the Require directive. The directive can be
> referenced within a , , or  section as
> well as .htaccess files to control access to particular parts of the
> server. Access can be controlled based on the client hostname or IP
> address.

You can find informations and example here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location and  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory.